# Getting my Discord Bot to Respond to a Certain Person

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I've tried multiple approaches; searching for names, using the names themselves plus the # and number (e.g. john#5645), and user id's (e.g. 4870410505695869), and none seem to work. Here is my current code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  msg = message.content
  if db["responding"]:
    options = starter_encouragements
    if "encouragements" in db.keys():
      options = options + db["encouragements"]

    if any(word in msg for word in sad_words):
      await message.channel.send(random.choice(options))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    if message.author.id == my id:
      return

    await message.channel.send(random.choice(options))
```

Comment: Don’t use dummy text to flout the automated filters in place. They are there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use multiple `on_message` events.**

Anything you can do in multiple events, you can also do in one.

There's also a logic error in the second event:

```
if message.author == client.user:
    if message.author.id == my id:  # This will never be true, unless you're using a selfbot
        return
```

Saying that, I believe this is what you're after based on your question:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
      return
  
    if message.author.id == YOUR_ID_HERE:
        msg = message.content
        if db["responding"]:
            options = starter_encouragements
            if "encouragements" in db.keys():
                options = options + db["encouragements"]
  
            if any(word in msg for word in sad_words):
                await message.channel.send(random.choice(options))
```

What that's doing is making sure to only send a random `encouragement` option if the message was sent by someone that has an ID matching the one you provide.

If this still doesn't work, make sure that you move any other `on_message` events into this one as well.